# Sending text messages (SMS) from Outlook 2016 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, sms

is there a way to send SMS from Outlook 2016 for Mac (my company is using O365)?

I know it is possible in the Windows version of Outlook (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Send-and-receive-text-messages-SMS-8a8c38d5-a197-4df7-929b-08c5e259a0ca, how about Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some commercial services like
[Red Oxygen](https://redoxygen.com/outlook-mobile-2016/)
with a 15 day trial for testing, which works from inside Outlook.

Another commercial approach is
[aspsms](https://www.aspsms.com/en/microsoft/office/outlook+2013-2016/)
which does Email to SMS from inside Outlook.

A possibly free solution (untested by me) might be to install Microsoft's
[Skype for Outlook.com](https://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-outlook-integration/).
One can
[send an SMS from Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3591/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-skype), but I do not know how well this works from Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I have bad news for you. In office 2016 Microsoft has discontinued the Outlook mobile service (SMS): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-sms-program/5624c906-ed0c-49f1-ad9f-c3ce0f760633.
Im pretty sure 3rd party will appear.

It was possible with outlook 2011 for mac short video how https://www.lynda.com/Outlook-Mac-tutorials/Sending-text-SMS-messages-from-Outlook/80853/82547-4.html.

In short, the idea was to send email to your mobile number and with the correct suffix for your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many different SMS recipients you are sending to, you can send them via the carrier provided service.

For example, I send SMS to myself and my wife often via outlook email using their carrier provided email to SMS address. This is simple since I know our carriers.

You can google "email to sms verizon tmobile etc..." to get carrier specific connector addresses. Example: 1234567890@vztext.com

Here is a list of some carriers and their SMS/MMS gateway domains: https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-send-e-mail-to-sms-text/

If I were sending to many people, this may not be a good solution. I have used this well for server alerting to a small group of team members via sms, or sending a reminders to myself or wife.

Comment: One thing: replying to messages sent like this needs MMS. SMS cannot send to an email address

Comment: I know I can do that, but I am looking for something that would keep the conversation thread.

Comment: Because an SMS technically is restricted to 160 characters, you'll want MMS unless the conversation thread is VERY short. Please excuse my sarcasm. I'm not sure what it means to "keep the conversation thread" and can not probably help any further.